# NavigationBar BACK button not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a NavigationViewController which root is a regular UIViewController.
I present a TableViewController programatically by:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTableViewVC", sender: nil)
```

This TableViewVC is showing the BACK button but it is not working at all.

The segue to this TableViewVC is a "show/push" segue.

How to navigate back to the UIViewController?

[image]

Comment: You need add another segue to previous VC to pop back, and add action to perform that segue

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, you are not using an `UINavigationController` to make navigation, you're using only segues don't you?

Comment: I have a NavigationController which embeds the root. I use a segue to show the DetailTableViewVC.

Comment: then you need a segue back to your previous viewController

Comment: ok, but I am not able to "draw" (option click) a segue from the back button to the rootVC. (The NavBar is automatically added by XCode)

Comment: add a segue from your viewController to your previous named it and performSegue with identifier in button action

Comment: I tried now every suggested method (also the below ones), but it wont pop: self.navigationController?.viewControllers `` prints [<MyApp.ViewController: 0x101c0c0b0>, <MyApp.TableViewController: 0x101c56cc0>]
`` could this be a bug? I think the latest approach you suggested stacks another VC on the stack and ends up in a megastack, which I wanna avoid.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Add a UIBarbutton into navigation controller in showTableViewVC.**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

     super.viewDidLoad()

     let backBarButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped(sender:))) as UIBarButtonItem 

     self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(backBarButton, animated: true)  

}
```

**2. Implement back button Action.**

```
func backButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) 
{
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: self.navigationController puts ``[<MyApp.ViewController: 0x101c0c0b0>, <MyApp.TableViewController: 0x101c56cc0>].`` So it seems to stack correctly also the backButtonTapped is triggered but ``popViewController(animated: true)`` or ``popToRoot``is not popping.